# Can't seem to get the correct return values from subprocess.Popen

Tags: python

In bash I am testing if a drive is mounted like this

```
if grep -qs "linuxLUN01" /proc/mounts; then
    ...do something...
```

Now I am trying to do the same thing in Python

```
DriveMounted = "grep -qs \"linuxLUN01\" /proc/mounts"

if sub.Popen(DriveMounted, shell=True):
    print "drive is mounted"
else:
    print "drive is not mounted"
```

everytime I run it I always get “drive is mounted” displayed whether the drive is really mounted or not i.e. the string ”linuxLUN01” appears in /proc/mounts.

I can’t figure out what’s wrong, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `subprocess.call()` instead:

```
import subprocess as sub
DriveMounted = "grep -qs \"linuxLUN01\" /proc/mounts"

if sub.call(DriveMounted, shell=True):
    print "drive is mounted"
else:
    print "drive is not mounted"
```

`subprocess.Popen` only returns a `Popen` instance but not the return value of the command it should execute.

`subprocess.call(...)` is a simple convenience function for `subprocess.Popen(...).wait()`.

Comment: Ok that explains why dmcc suggested code with p.wait(), changing popen to call did the trick thanks

Answer (score 0):

`sub.Popen(DriveMounted, shell=True)` constructs a `Popen` object which will always be `True` -- this doesn't actually run the command. You probably want something more like this:

```
import subprocess as sub
p = sub.Popen(['grep', '-qs', 'linuxLUN01', '/proc/mounts'], stdout=sub.PIPE)
p.wait() # waits for the command to finish running
mounted = bool(p.stdout.read()) # see if grep produced any output
print "drive is", "mounted" if mounted else "not mounted"
```

Comment: Thanks for the info I was not aware of Popen beeing always True.

Comment: `wait()` doesn't run the command, but waits for it to finish. The process does start when you call the Popen constructor.